# Make two column dropdown sub-menu mobile responsive

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, mobile

This is my website, http://brightlegal.co.uk/. Under the "Services" menu item, there are two sub-menus, "Services for Individuals" and "Services for Businesses". I've tried to make them mobile responsive (or at least, look better on mobile) and this is the css I have so far:

```
#main-nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
#main-nav ul {
  width: 400px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 725px) {
#headerwrap #main-nav {
    width: 920%;
}
#headerwrap #main-nav li {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    clear: none;
    text-align: left;

#main-nav ul {
    width: 150px;

}}
```

This kind of works, I've used http://www.studiopress.com/responsive/ to see how it looks at different sizes. It seems to work best at 480px, but overlaps the sides of the screens any smaller than that. At 768px (portrait iPad), it switches back to the desktop menu, but this overlaps the logo. How can I fix this, or switch portrait iPad to the mobile menu?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On mobile, can you set the width of the dropdown menu at 100%? also remove a little bit the margin/padding right and left of the two sub-menus?

Comment: Also are you using bootstrap?

Comment: If I set the width to 100% then it only seems to extend as far as the little menu button box and cuts off all of the text. If I change it to this:
    @media screen and (max-width: 725px) {
    #main-nav {
        width: 100%;
    }
    #headerwrap #main-nav li {
        width: 150px;
        float: left;
        clear: none;
        text-align: left;

    #main-nav ul {
        width: 150px;

    }}

Then it seems to work a little better, but I lose the right-side of the sub-menu. Currently using Wordpress, a Themify theme, the Themify builder plugin and custom CSS.